# Cannot cast varbinary to varchar in presto

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I have a column which is in varbinary.
I tried

```
select cast(msg as varchar) 
from table 
WHERE DATE(datestr) > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY
```

which threw

> Cannot cast row(row1 varbinary) to varchar

and when I try

```
from table 
WHERE DATE(datestr) > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY
```

I get

> Unexpected parameters (row(row1 varbinary)) for function from_utf8. Expected: from_utf8(varbinary, varchar(x)) , from_utf8(varbinary, bigint) , from_utf8(varbinary) "

I also tried,

```
select from_utf8(msg) 
from table 
WHERE DATE(datestr) > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY
```

which threw

> Unexpected parameters (row(row1 varbinary)) for function from_utf8. Expected: from_utf8(varbinary, varchar(x)) , from_utf8(varbinary, bigint) , from_utf8(varbinary) "

I have tried several things online but doesn't have seemed to help. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on exception - `msg` column is not a `varbinary` but rather a [`ROW`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#row) with one `varbinary` field named `row1`. You can access it with field reference operator `.` via name (`msg.row1`):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (msg, id) AS (
    VALUES (cast(row (to_utf8(cast(now() as varchar))) as row(row1 varbinary)), 1)
)

-- query
select from_utf8(msg.row1) 
from dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-05-14 14:09:30.391 UTC |